# redux: how to update related info in store

Tags: redux, ngrx

I have a (ngrx) store for an array of Speaker object and for the SelectedSpeaker. The reducer looks like:

```
export const speakers = (state: any = [], { type, payload }) => {

  switch (type) {

      case SpeakerActions.TOGGLEFAVORITE:
          return state.map(speaker => { 
            return speaker.id === payload.id ? _.assign({}, speaker, {isFavorite: !speaker.isFavorite}) : speaker;
          }); 

    }

}
```

I left out the unimportant code. The reducer for currentSpeaker looks like:

```
export const selectedSpeaker = (state: any = [], { type, payload }) => {

    switch (type) {

        case SelectedSpeakerActions.SELECT:            
            return payload;
    }  

}
```

Now my question, if I dispatch a SpeakerActions.TOGGLEFAVORITE for a speaker and this happens to be the SelectedSpeaker, how do I update the SelectedSpeaker in this case? Note this all works as part of an Angular2 project, for what that worth.

Comment: @TomW is right, you should rather use an id, which should be the id of the selected user. I've made a topic about ngrx in stackoverflow documentation, if you're not familiar to ngrx it might help :) ! http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/8086/ngrx#t=201612051500428489056

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Redux state should be fully normalized - you shouldn't have some state in two places, since it creates exactly the problem you are seeing.

Probably the best solution in your case is for selectedSpeaker just to contain the id of the selected speaker, not the speaker itself. e.g. something like

```
export const selectedSpeaker = (state: any = [], { type, payload }) => {

    switch (type) {

        case SelectedSpeakerActions.SELECT:            
            return payload.id;
    }  

}
```

Obviously, you'll need to lookup the selected speaker where you use it, using the ID. You might also find it easier to have an object (or Map) from id=>speaker in your speaker store, rather than a plain array.

Comment: OK, on one hand this makes sense. On the other hand, if I change the SelectedSpeaker when using the speaker object everything is updated straight away without the need to build code to fetch the new (selected) speaker object in every component in which I use SelectedSpeaker.

Comment: `function getSelectedSpeaker(state) { ... }` Only write the function once, and then re-use it where ever you need it.